# How is research level calculated?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

For the longest the time, I assumed that research level was heavily tied to how many you have caught for each species. Well my assumption was invalidated after maxing out this Skuntanks research level

[image: Skuntank max research]

My first and only capture of this Pokémon was an alpha, and it marked off a few tasks. I was surprised to see that the research level was fully complete. I then thought it may have to do with the task that have the red arrows next to it, but the math doesn’t add up.

So exactly how is the Pokémons research level calculated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Research level is based on the checkmarks on the screen, not just based on the number caught (although that number is usually one of the things that gives you checkmarks).

Further, the [red arrows on the left indicate rows that are double points](https://pokejungle.net/pokemon-legends-arceus/pokedex-research-level-guide/) - so you got:

- 2 points for catching one
- 1 for catching an alpha
- 2 for seeing Venoshock three times
- 4 for seeing it use Flamethrower three times
- 1 for using a strong style move

Resulting in 10 points.