# What does a red arrow icon next to a research task mean?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

In the Research Tasks section of the Pokédex, some tasks have a red arrow icon next to them. What do these red arrows mean?

[image: Research Tasks for Bidoof]

Comment: Related (maybe dup?): [How is research level calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/395366/124566). The double arrows mean you get double the research points

Comment: Yep, definitely a dupe